# ros Map_server could not open map

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Could use some help on this one.

This one works on my robot (I copy the map files manually to the /tmp directory before roslaunching it):

```
 <launch>
    
      <!--- Run the kinect -->
      <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/kinect.launch" />
    
      <!-- Run the map server -->
      <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/tmp/my_map_waalre.yaml" />
    
      <!--- Run AMCL -->
      <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/config/amcl_turtlebot.launch" />
    
      <!--- Run Move Base -->
      <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/config/move_base_turtlebot.launch" />
    
    </launch>
```

But this one not and comes with error

```
<launch>

  <!--- Run the kinect -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/kinect.launch" />

  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/turtelbot/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/robo/my_map_waalre.yaml" />

  <!--- Run AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/config/amcl_turtlebot.launch" />

  <!--- Run Move Base -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/config/move_base_turtlebot.launch" />

</launch>
```

So same file but just in a different directory. I must be overseeing something simple.
error it produces:

process[map_server-8]: started with pid [20619]
[ERROR] [1389437922.013953806]: Map_server could not open /home/turtelbot/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/robo/my_map_waalre.yaml.
process[amcl-9]: started with pid [20630]
process[move_base-10]: started with pid [20679]
[map_server-8] process has died [pid 20619, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/navigation/map_server/bin/map_server /home/turtelbot/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/robo/my_map_waalre.yaml __name:=map_server __log:=/home/turtelbot/.ros/log/531236a0-7aaf-11e3-8077-94dbc9f717d5/map_server-8.log].
log file: /home/turtelbot/.ros/log/531236a0-7aaf-11e3-8077-94dbc9f717d5/map_server-8*.log

Any clues?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117016/ros-map_server-could-not-open-map/) by [Charel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3796/charel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2014-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

by writing down the question it triggers the mind. Opened the .yaml file and there was a reference of the .pgm file in the /tmp directory. Updated it and now it works.

---

Originally posted by [Charel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3796/charel/) with karma: 81 on 2014-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bahaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/10376/bahaa/) on 2014-08-25**:
i faced the same problem, but i didn't fund in the yaml file any reference to the .pgm file!

**Comment by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on 2015-03-04**:
yes, it has a reference to the .pgm file in the yaml file. Open the yaml file, and you could find these word in the first line::image: /home/...../name.pgm

**Comment by [Elise](https://answers.ros.org/users/23626/elise/) on 2015-08-19**:
How exactly did you update it?

**Comment by [Charel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3796/charel/) on 2015-08-20**:
indeed, open .yaml file with text editor like gedit, in the first line you will find the path name.